# If $P$ is a projection and $T$ is positive operator such that $P\leq T$, then why $P(H)\subset\sqrt{T}(H)$?

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, projection, self-adjoint-operators

Suppose that $H$ is a Hilbert space. If $P\colon H\to H$ is a projection (i.e. $P^{2}=P^{*}=P$) and $T\colon H\to H$ is positive operator (i.e. $T\geq0$) such that $P\leq T$, then why $P(H)\subset\sqrt{T}(H)$? Here $\leq$ denotes the [usual partial order on self-adjoint operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_element). I know that this result is true if $T$ is a projection, but I don't see the general case. I see that $P=\sqrt{P}\leq\sqrt{T}$ though. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to prove that if $0\leq A\leq B$, then [there exists a contraction $C$ such that $A^{1/2}=CB^{1/2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3355657/22857).

So in your case, as $P^{1/2}=P$, you have $P=CT^{1/2}$. Taking adjoints, $P=T^{1/2}C^*$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I see your point! If $T$ is compact, do you know why this implies that $P$ has finite rank? I can only conclude that $\sqrt{T}$ is compact.

Comment: Yes. If $P$ has infinite rank, then its (closed) image is infinite-dimensional. So $T^{1/2}$ applies to the unit ball cannot be compact (it contains the closed unit ball of the image of $P$). Thus $T^{1/2}$ is not compact, and neither is $T$.

Comment: So I assume one cannot take a shortcut by proving that $P(H)\subset T(H)$ and conclude from this that $P$ has finite rank. In other words, does one really need to use the square root of $T$ to conclude that $P$ has finite rank? The square root feels like a detour.

Comment: At first sight, I wouldn't know how to prove that. Note that in general, the inclusion $\operatorname{ran}T\subset \operatorname{ran}T^{1/2}$ is proper.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your help! To be honest, I don't understand your argument on why $T^{1/2}$ is not compact. Why can $T^{1/2}(\text{ball}(H))$ not be compact if $P(H)$ is finite dimensional? And why does this imply that $T^{1/2}(\text{ball}(H))$ cannot be pre-compact (since this is the definition of compact operators)?

Comment: I assume "finite" was a typo. If $P$ has infinite-dimensional range, its range is an infinite-dimensional closed subspace $PH$. Take an orthonormal basis$\{e_j\}$  for $PH$; this is inside the unit ball of $H$. An orthonormal basis does not have a convergent subsequence. As $e_j=T^{1/2}C^*e_j$ and $C$ is a contraction, you get that $\{e_j\}\subset T^{1/2}(\operatorname{ball}H)$.